# Generator with return statement

Tags: python, generator

During my coverage, I scratched my head on the following case (python 3.4)

```
def simple_gen_function(str_in, sep=""):
    if sep == "":
        yield str_in[0]
        for c in str_in[1:]:
            yield c
    else:
        return str_in
        # yield from str_in

str_in = "je teste "
t = "".join(simple_gen_function(str_in))
p = "".join(simple_gen_function(str_in, "\n"))

print("%r %r" % (t, p))
# 'je teste' ''
```

Using return in the generator, the return was not "reached" while using `yield from str_in` I have the expected result.

The question seems simple, but I believed that using return in a generator, it was in reached.

Comment: `return` has a different behaviour in a generator then a normal function, it is the value in the `StopIteration` that is raised when the generator finishes, a function with `yield` cannot just return a value instead you would need the generator as a helper function and another one that either returns the string unchanged or returns the generator object.

Comment: What makes you think it wasn't reached?

Comment: In the case of yield was never reached, why the "function" still act as generator ?

Comment: @AliSAIDOMAR the presence of `yield` anywhere at all in the function turns the *whole* thing into a generator, all the time. It doesn't matter if a yield is never reached.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The presence of `yield` in a function body turns it into a generator function instead of a normal function.  And in a generator function, using `return` is a way of saying "The generator has ended, there are no more elements." By having the first statement of a generator method be `return str_in`, you are guaranteed to have a generator that returns no elements.

As a comment mentions, the return value *is* used as an argument to the `StopIteration` exception that gets raised when the generator has ended.  See:

```
>>> gen = simple_gen_function("hello", "foo")
>>> next(gen)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration: hello
```

### If there's a `yield` anywhere in your `def`, it's a generator!

In the comments, the asker mentions they thought the function turned into a generator dynamically, when the yield statement is executed. But this is not how it works! The decision is made before the code is ever excuted. If Python finds a `yield` anywhere at all under your `def`, it turns that `def` into a generator function.

See this ultra-condensed example:

```
>>> def foo():
...     if False:
...         yield "bar"
...     return "baz"
>>> foo()
<generator object foo at ...>
>>> # The return value "baz" is only exposed via StopIteration
>>> # You probably shouldn't use this behavior.
>>> next(foo())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
StopIteration: baz
>>> # Nothing is ever yielded from the generator, so it generates no values.
>>> list(foo())
[]
```

Comment: Thanks, I believed that was the "reach" of the "yield" statement turning a function as generator.