# Getting return value of generator via iteration

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, coroutine

I am having a hard time reconciling these two:

```
const gen = function *() {
  yield 3;
  yield 4;
  return 5;
};

const rator = gen();

console.log(rator.next());  //  { value: 3, done: false }
console.log(rator.next());  //  { value: 4, done: false }
console.log(rator.next());  //  { value: 5, done: true }
```

The above we see all 3 values, if we call next() a fourth time, we get:

```
{ value: undefined, done: true }
```

which makes sense. But now if we use it in a loop:

```
for(let v of gen()){
  console.log('next:', v); // next: 3, next: 4
}
```

I guess I am confused why using the for-loop doesn't print `next: 5`, but calling next() on the iterator manually can get the `return` value. Can anyone explain why this is?

In other words, I would expect the `for loop` to print `next: 5` but it doesn't.

Comment: The for loop is over as soon as `done` is  true. The return value isn't part of the iterated sequence. It's frequently undefined.

Comment: right so the loop discards the value that accompanies the first done:true object. seems weird.

Answer (score 0):

For consistency, this seems to work?

```
const gen = function *() {
  yield 3;
  yield 4;
  return yield 5;
};
```

the `return` keyword doesn't seem to do anything now, though.

Comment: This just yields 5 and then returns undefined on the next iteration. `done` is still false when it yields 5. You might as well just remove the `return` -- it's the same.

Answer (score -1):

The returned value is contained in `exception.value`, where `exception` is the StopIteration that is thrown by the generator instance when the generator frame returns.

Example:

```py
def generator_function():
    yield 0
    yield 1
    return "text"

value_list = []
exception_list = []
try:
    a = generator_function()
    while True:
        value_list.append(next(a))
except StopIteration as e:
    exception_list.append(e)

print(value_list)
print(exception_list)
print(type(exception_list[0]), exception_list[0])
print(type(exception_list[0].value), exception_list[0].value)
```

Also see [Generator with return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661068/generator-with-return-statement)